# Setting object values in php factory or factory method

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a little question, is setting values in factory method correctly ?

Something like this:

```
class ObjectFactory {
     public static function create($config)
     {
          $object = new Object();
          $object->setDependency(// something);
          $object->setValue(// something);
          return $object;
     }
}
```

Is it correctly? Maybe it should be builder? How should i call it? ObjectBuilder, ObjectFactory, or maybe ObjectCreator?

Please explain me cases of creating object with some dependencies or initial values. I know it should be builder pattern but i heard that builder is something advanced than just returning object with few initial values or dependencies. So... what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Builder is used when you have multiple ways to construct/config an object after instancing it, but those ways share common general steps. So you abstract those steps into an interface called `Builder`, then you have a class named `Director` which uses the `Builder` interface to call those steps in the order you want.

Secondly, your posted code is not about [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in which a factory method is a method acted like a template in a base class, and will be implemented in derived classes.

The pattern in your code is typically called `Factory Pattern` where you just encapsulate a particular process of constructing an object into a method so you can easily reuse it.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thank you for help :) But what with case when i want to instancing some root object that have many nested smaller objects with setters and getters. Then builder comes with help ?

Comment: No, in that case you should still go with Factory Pattern.